# What is the proper way to swap out an existing JPanel in a JFrame with another?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm building a program that requires swapping out the current, visible JPanel with another. Unfortunately there seems to be multiple to go about this and all of my attempts have ended in failure. I can successfully get the first JPanel to appear in my JFrame, but swapping JPanels results in a blank JFrame.

My Main JFrame:

```
public class ShellFrame {

static CardLayout cl = new CardLayout(); //handles panel switching
static JFrame frame; //init swing on EDT
static MainMenu mm; 
static Panel2 p2;
static Panel3 p3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initFrame();
}

public static void initFrame() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
              frame = new JFrame();
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
              frame.setLayout(cl);

              mm = new MainMenu();
              pp = new PlacementPanel();

              //first panel added to frame will always show first
              frame.add(mm, "MainMenu");
              frame.pack(); //sizes frame to fit the panel being shown
              frame.setVisible(true);
         }
    });
}

public static void switchPanel(String name) {
    cl.show(frame.getContentPane(), name);
    frame.pack();
}

public static void updatePanel2(/* args */) {
   frame.removeAll();
   p2 = new Panel2(/* args */);
   frame.add(pp, "PlacementPanel");
   frame.pack();
   frame.validate();
   frame.repaint();  
}
```

I'm trying to use updatePanel2 to swap out the existing panel with a new Panel2 but It doesn't seem to be working. Panel2 works fine on it's own but trying to use it in conjunction with my program simply yields a blank window. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I like to do `frame.setContentPane(thepanel)`

Comment: @Fernando How would I use it in conjunction with my updatePanel function? I tried a variety of combinations of it and my existing function but to no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`that requires swapping out the current, visible JPanel with another`

Have a look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a complete example of how to do it properly.

Comment: I've tried the card layout as well and got the same result. My problem is I don't know how to make my updatePanel function that removes the old, unneeded frames, and adds a new one (created from dynamic data existing elsewhere In the program).

Comment: @AgentJWall, `I've tried the card layout as well and got the same result` Well read the `CardLayout` tutorial (you've been given the link) and use the example program from the tutorial and customize it for your requirements. That is start with working code and then customize it instead of trying to write you code from scratch if you are not sure what you are doing. The code you posted is NOT the way the class should be coded. You should NOT be using static varaibles and methods everywhere. The CardLayout is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Swing app which 'swaps' Panels when the user press the 'SPACE' key, showing a live plot of a running simulation. What i did goes like this:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    // Called when the JPanel is added to the JFrame
    public void addNotify() {

        super.addNotify();
        animator = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        animator.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1000L/60L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (spacePressed) 
            plot.render(g);
        else
            simulation.render(g);
    }

    public void run() {

        simulation.update(); 
        repaint();
    }
}

public class PlotView {

    public void render(Graphics g) {
         //draw the plot here
    }
}

public class SimulationView {

    public void render(Graphics g) {
         //draw simulation here
    }
}
```

This works very well for my 'show live plot' problem. And there's also the `CardLayout` approach, which you may turn into a new separate question if you having trouble. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should do `.setVisible(false);` to the panel which you want to be replaced.

Here is a working example, it switches the panels when you press "ENTER";
If you copy this in an IDE, automatically get the imports (shift+o in Eclipse);

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private JButton button = new JButton("Change Panels");
    private JPanel panelOnFrame = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    public MyFrame() {
        // adding labels to panels, to distinguish them
        panelOnFrame.add(new JLabel("panel on frame"));
        panel1.add(new JLabel("panel 1"));      

        setSize(new Dimension(250,250));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(button);
        add(panelOnFrame);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
```

//+-------------here is the replacement:

```
            panelOnFrame.setVisible(false);
            this.add(panel1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```