# Java switch between panels (using custom buttons) on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to make a some kind of modern GUI that has tabs on left, like shown on this picture:

[image]

Any ideas how could I make panels switch between while not disposing data that's written/set, for example into text fields, text area, check boxs, scroll bars and etc.?

I was thinking about just removing old one panel and adding another panel, but when I click on panel I visited before controls data will have been reset, and I think it would flicker.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for switching panels

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks! Solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to swap out an existing JPanel in a JFrame with another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315416/what-is-the-proper-way-to-swap-out-an-existing-jpanel-in-a-jframe-with-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Frakcool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180785/frakcool):

Use a CardLayout for switching panels

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but you could try this;

Make a JTabbedPane, add it to the JFrame's contentPane. 
add JPanels to the tabs. 
then make sure that the tabs are aligned left and vertical by doing the following: 
tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.LEFT); 
and then, you can even do this: 
JTabbedPane .setTabComponentAt(1, new WebVerticalLabel("Title1")); 
to make the label text displayed vertical. 
I hope this helps you, 
Lenard